# custom useElementSize hook doesn't update on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I made the following hook to track the size of a HTML element using useRef but it for some reason it doesn't update on the first render, do you know how to fix it ?

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function getElementSize({offsetWidth, offsetHeight}) {
    return {
        width: offsetWidth,
        height: offsetHeight
    }
}

const useElementSize = (elementRef) => {
    const [elementSize, setElementSize] = useState({
        width: 0, 
        height: 0
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = () => {
            if(elementRef == null) return
            setElementSize(getElementSize(elementRef))
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", listener)
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", listener)
    }, [elementRef])
    return elementSize
}

export default useElementSize
```

This is where I call the custom hook :

```
    const buttonRef = useRef(null)
    const elementSize = useElementSize(buttonRef.current)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(elementSize) // { width: 0, height: 0 }
        console.log(buttonRef) // { current: button.path-button }
    }, [elementSize])

    return <button ref={buttonRef} className="path-button">
        <div className="content">
            <div className="path"></div>
            {children && <p className="text">{children}</p>}
        </div>
    </button>
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't update on the first render"? Should it not be `(0, 0)`? You pass `(0, 0)` as initial value for `elementSize` and you only call `setElementSize` when `resize` gets emitted.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs I want useElementSize to update its state with the correct size once the ref is loaded, right now it stays {0, 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I needed (tracks the size of an element in real time):

```
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';

const useElementSize = (elementRef) => {
    const [elementSize, setElementSize] = useState({
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
    })
    const listener = useCallback(() => elementRef?.current && setElementSize({
            width: elementRef.current.offsetWidth,
            height: elementRef.current.offsetHeight,
        }), [elementRef]
    )
    useEffect(() => {
        listener()
        window.addEventListener("resize", listener)
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", listener)
    }, [])
    return elementSize
}

export default useElementSize
```

As Kelvin Schoofs said it's also doable using a function inside ref={}

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) of `useRef`:

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is
> initialized to the passed argument (`initialValue`). **The returned object
> will persist for the full lifetime of the component.**

Therefore your dependency array of `[elementRef]` makes it that your `useEffect` only fires **once**. Use `[elementRef.current]` instead, since that's the actual value you care about and that's the actual value that changes.

Alternatively, you can use [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) instead.

---

I didn't realize you were passing `buttonRef.current` to the hook, not `buttonRef`. In that case, the answer to why it doesn't update is a lot simpler: React doesn't re-render your component just because a ref's `.current` changes. Therefore the `useEffect` doesn't get called again anyway. My alternatively solution of "use callback refs" is actually what you need here, something like this:

```js
const useElementSize = () => {
    const [elementSize, setElementSize] = useState({
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    })
    const onRef = useCallback((elementRef) => {
        if (elementRef == null) return;
        setElementSize(getElementSize(elementRef));
    }, []);
    return [elementSize, onRef]
}



const [elementSize, elementRef] = useElementSize();
// ...
return <button ref={elementRef} className="path-button">
```

Comment: I'm passing buttonRef.current to the hook not buttonRef

Comment: Ah I had the right idea but in the wrong direction. I'll update the answer.